# Xamarin.iOS + Xamarin.Forms - custom renderer in an iOS class library not found

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, libraries

I have four libraries all in all, a PCL and three platform-specific class libraries for Android, iOS and Win Phone. I have a base class for a custom Xamarin.Forms view in the PCL and renderers for it in the platform-specific libraries.

In the project where I use the libraries, the `OnElementChanged()` function of the iOS renderer is never called. I have tested on Android thus far, and there it works and the view gets rendered. Why might this be?

To complicate things, I have used the libraries in another project, where they work seamlessly on all three platforms.

I can provide more information if needed.

Comment: Anything you can share, code-wise? Are you making sure to properly export the renderer, and certain that it's actually being used?

Answer (score 1):

As there is not much info...

1. Make sure ExportRendererAttribute is set for the renderer
2. Make sure only one renderer available for the Control